# DMARC report with passing O365 DKIM signature being sent by Google server

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

The dmarc report values are as follows:

```
dkim_domain : mydomain.onmicrosoft.com
dkim_result : pass
selector : selector1-mydomain-onmicrosoft-com
header_from : mydomain
spf_domain : mydomain
spf_result : fail
source_ip : 209.85.219.70   (this is a Google mail server)
org_name : google.com
```

So, we have a message that was signed by O365, but is being sent by a Google server, and the receiving Google server is reporting it as a SPF violation.  How does this happen?  Is there anything to be done about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a forwarded message. SPF does not survive forwarding and, therefore, any mail forwarding service should rewrite the *envelope sender*. That will break the DMARC alignment through SPF, but a message signed with DKIM should be enough to provide proper alignment.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I had concluded as well.